How to get an overlying 1-surv curve on the competing risk outcome graph (Cumulative Incidence) graph
I'm completely new to Survival in R.
I'm performing Competing risk outcome analysis(Cumulative Incidence). I used cmprsk package for this. Now, I would like to overlay the reference category or censored level survival probability curve i.e.,(1- (sum of probability of other events)) on the Cumulative Incidence graph.
I tried the following code.
  #Example
  set.seed(123)
  time <- round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 40), 2)
  event <- sample(0:3, 100, replace = TRUE)
  data <- data.frame(time = time, event = event)
  head(data)
  
  CI_ex<-cmprsk::cuminc(ftime = data$time, fstatus = data$event, cencode =0)
plot.cuminc(CI_ex)  

I got the following picture.

I would like to get a graph with a red line:

(the red line is 1-(sum of probability of events)).
I would also like to get a risk table of this.
